# Delete a workflow instance from a survey

Tags: 2010, list, workflow, survey

In SharePoint Designer I'm able find my survey under List and Libraries and create a Workflow for it. Once I've published it, I went back in and made changes, than I re-published the workflow. The problem is, there are now two versions of my workflow attached to that survey. How do I delete the previous version? This is extreamly easy to do when dealing with a list. I just edit the workflow settings in the browser and delete that instance of the workflow. How do you delete a workflow from a survey?

Comment: Could you sign my answer as a correct if it helps you, please?

Answer (score 1):

You could use SharePoint Designer to delete your workflow. In part List and Libraries you have your Survey too. Open this Survey list and go to Workflows. Check your workflow and delete it. That's all. See instructions below.

[image]

[image]